# Is this lens for a Minolta mount?

Tags: lens, lens-mount, minolta

I am pretty sure I bought this on eBay but it was five years ago.  I'm planning on adapting it to my Micro Four Thirds camera, and suspect it is a Minolta Rokkor.

[image]

Here is an imgur gallery with more photos: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx481.jpg

Comment: Can you describe the mount in the title? This isn't a forum — we'd like good descriptions that make it easy for other people with similar problems to find.

Comment: BTW, Rokkor is really a name for a line of Minolta's own MC/MD mount lenses (and a few non-MC/MD manual focus lenses!), using it as a generic name is confusing...

Comment: BBTW, just try it on a cheap (but not TOO cheap) MD adapter. This is a medium-quality classic telezoom, quality might just be good enough to be fun on MFT. Just  expect to have to deal with some CA and fringing in post in the worst case. About mechanical lens adapters: The $12 kind often only works well with OEM lenses (and gives strange mechanical issues with third party ones), the $25 kind is often great enough!

Answer (score 4):

This is a Minolta MD lens mount. It's hard to see in your photo, but by increasing the brightness, you can see the shutter-preferred auto-exposure lug (called the MD lug) (blue arrow), and the meter coupling (MC) tab (red arrow). These lugs identify it as a MD mount lens.

See also:

- [Minolta SLR Lens Mounts](https://web.archive.org/web/20180126214639/http://www.subclub.org/minman/mounts.htm)
- [Minolta SR-mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minolta_SR-mount) (Wikipedia)

[image]

Comment: Where is the aperture pin? SRD (a/k/a MD) mount lenses have aperture pins.

Comment: On this lens, it's not a pin, it's the flattened tab at the top (11:30). Look closely, there's a slot the tab rotates in. I wish the image had a bit more contrast, it would have made the tabs & pins more obvious. =/

Comment: Yeah, on your brightened version of the image you can barely almost see it. It looked like a cutout on the lug in the darker original.

Comment: The notched flange is already a dead giveaway, although it can still create confusion with Konica AR mount :)

Comment: @rackandboneman well, the notched flange opposite the aperture pin is a dead giveaway that it's at least a Minolta SR mount. But the other linkages distinguish it as a MD mount. But yeah, the notch screamed Minolta.